# Use Model.save() on Adding Many-to-Many Relationships?

Tags: django

I am trying to create custom Django migration files to prepopulate my database during development. The problem is, that I populate some model values on the Model.save() method. See **models.py**:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('kitchen name', max_length=150, blank=False, unique=True)
    related_users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='kitchens', blank=True)
    secret_code = models.CharField('kitchen code', max_length=9, blank=True, unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.secret_code:
            self.secret_code = self.generate_random_code()
        super(Kitchen, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def generate_random_code(self, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
        """
        creates a string out of 6 random characters
        """
        code_digit_num = 9
        return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(code_digit_num))
```

In my migration file, however, I am trying to add some users to the related_users field, which returns an error.

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique
>   constraint "customer_exemple_secret_code_key" DETAIL:  Key
>   (secret_code)=() already exists.

The function to add the data looks like this:

```
def add_example_data(apps, shema_editor):
    Model1 = apps.get_model("customer", "Model1")
    Customer = apps.get_model("customer", "Customer")
    User = apps.get_model("user", "User")
    for example_dict in DATA:
        k = Model1.objects.create(
            name=example_dict["name"],)
            related_customer=Customer.objects.get(name=example_dict["related_customer"])
        )
        for related_user_instance in example_dict["related_user"]:
            u = User.objects.get(email=related_user_instance)
            k.related_users.add(u)
```

I think the problem is, that the `.add` method uses the `.bulk_create` method, which will not call `.save()` on the model and therefore creates some not unique value for the secret code (I don't know why?). Is there a way to create m2m relationships by calling `.save()` or do I have this problem all wrong?

Comment: 1. You are showing the code for `Model2`, but you are creating `Model1` instances. Please show the code for `Model1`. 2. The IntegrityError is raised not by the addition of related users, but likely during the creation of `Model1`. What code line does the error point to?

Comment: Oh, I corrected it. I tried to simplify the code a little for this post mislabeled the models. The most recent call in the error Traceback points to "...db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute"

Comment: Scan the traceback to find the affected line in the migration file (presumably in `add_example_data`).